# Copying Data from MySQL database once primary server is back online

Tags: mysql, rsync

I'm following this tutorial http://www.howto-expert.com/how-to-create-a-server-failover-solution/ and was wondering if someone would be able to help me write a script which will copy the data back over to the primary once it's back online.

Basically the way it works is;

The setup has 2 servers (Primary and secondary). Both run a parralel wordpress e-commerce website kept in sync using mysqldump and rsync every 5 minutes. I use a service called DNSmadeeasy Failover which checks for a viable connection. If the primary website is down, it switches to the secondary, then when the primary is back up, it changes the ip back to the primary server. If someone happens to register for the website or place an order, then the secondary now has the latest copy of the database.

The tutorial fails to go into detail on how to copy the latest version of the data inside the database back to the primary after it goes live. If the primary is down for a long time, the secondary server will then have the most up to date copy.

http://pho.to/8Zjsp

Answer (score 0):

Before mysqldump and rsync from primary to secondary, you can check a flag existing only on secondary server which says "there are changes from operations". Then you make sync in the other way and clear the flag.

Comment: Is there a link to a tutorial I can follow? Or would you be able to walk me through it via e-mail?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with master - master asynchronous replication . if its any one server is down bin-log having all the changes , once its up apply all the changes in primary or secondary server.

MySQL documentation available to configure replication .

Comment: one server on shared hosting, so can't do that, thanks for the answer